# data points to plot. Error: plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to add labels to my data points in a plot, but when I try to do this using the text() function, I get the error message "Error in text.default(CPI2013, GCB2013, labels = wbcode) : plot.new has not been called yet"

```
scatterGCBPI<-ggplot(TreismanData3, aes(CPI2013, GCB2013))
scatterGCBPI+geom_point(position = "jitter", na.rm = TRUE)
+geom_smooth(method = loess)+labs(x="Perception", 
y="Experience")+theme_bw()+text(CPI2013,GCB2013, labels = wbcode)
```

TreismanData3:

```
  structure(list(country = c("Aruba", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
"Angola", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
"Antigua and Barbuda", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Burundi", "Belgium", "Benin", "Burkina Faso", "Bangladesh", 
"Bulgaria", "Bahrain", "Bahamas, The", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Belarus", "Belize", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Barbados", "Brunei Darussalam", 
"Bhutan", "Botswana", "Central African Republic", "Canada", "Switzerland", 
"Chile", "China", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cameroon", "Congo, Rep.", 
"Colombia", "Comoros", "Cape Verde", "Costa Rica", "Cuba", "Cyprus", 
"Czech Republic", "Germany", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Denmark", 
"Dominican Republic", "Algeria", "Ecuador", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", 
"Eritrea", "Spain", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "Fiji", 
"France", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", "Gabon", "United Kingdom", 
"Georgia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Gambia, The", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guyana", 
"Hong Kong SAR, China", "Honduras", "Croatia", "Haiti", "Hungary", 
"Indonesia", "India", "Ireland", "Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iraq", 
"Iceland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Japan", "St. Kitts and Nevis", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Cambodia", "Kiribati", 
"Korea, Rep.", "Kuwait", "Lao PDR", "Lebanon", "Liberia", "Libya", 
"St. Lucia", "Liechtenstein", "Sri Lanka", "Lesotho", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Latvia", "Kosovo", "Namibia", "Macao SAR, China", 
"Morocco", "Monaco", "Moldova", "Madagascar", "Maldives", "Mexico", 
"Macedonia, FYR", "Mali", "Malta", "Myanmar", "Mongolia", "Mozambique", 
"Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
"Nicaragua", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Nepal", "Nauru", "New Zealand", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Palau", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Papua New Guinea", "Poland", "Puerto Rico", "Korea, Dem. Rep.", 
"Portugal", "Paraguay", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "Samoa", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Singapore", "Solomon Islands", 
"Sierra Leone", "El Salvador", "San Marino", "Somalia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Sudan", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Sweden", "Swaziland", 
"Seychelles", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Chad", "Togo", "Thailand", 
"Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Timor-Leste", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Tuvalu", "Taiwan", "Tanzania", "Uganda", 
"Ukraine", "Uruguay", "United States", "Uzbekistan", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Venezuela, RB", "Vietnam", "Vanuatu", "West Bank and Gaza", 
"Yemen, Rep.", "Serbia", "South Africa", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), wbcode = c("ABW", "ADO", "AFG", "AGO", 
"ALB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", 
"BEL", "BEN", "BFA", "BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", 
"BLZ", "BOL", "BRA", "BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", 
"CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "CIV", "CMR", "COG", "COL", "COM", "CPV", 
"CRI", "CUB", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", 
"DZA", "ECU", "EGY", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", 
"FRA", "FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", 
"GNQ", "GRC", "GRD", "GTM", "GUY", "HKG", "HND", "HRV", "HTI", 
"HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", 
"JAM", "JOR", "JPN", "K", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", "KHM", "KIR", 
"KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", "LCA", "LIE", "LKA", 
"LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "LWI", "M", "MAC", "MAR", "MCO", 
"MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MKD", "MLI", "MLT", "MMR", "MNG", 
"MOZ", "MRT", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NLD", 
"NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PCI", "PER", 
"PHL", "PNG", "POL", "PRI", "PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "QAT", "ROM", 
"RUS", "RWA", "SAM", "SAU", "SEN", "SGP", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", 
"SMR", "SOM", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "SWZ", "SYC", 
"SYR", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TMP", "TON", "TTO", 
"TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", "TZA", "UGA", "UKR", "URY", "USA", 
"UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VNM", "VUT", "WBG", "YEM", "YUG", "ZAF", 
"ZAR", "ZMB", "ZWE"), CPI2013 = c(NA, NA, 0.8, 2.3, 3.1, 6.9, 
3.4, 3.6, NA, 8.1, 6.9, 2.8, 2.1, 7.5, 3.6, 3.8, 2.7, 4.1, 4.8, 
7.1, 4.2, 2.9, NA, 3.4, 4.2, 7.5, 6, 6.3, 6.4, 2.5, 8.1, 8.5, 
7.1, 4, 2.7, 2.5, 2.2, 3.6, 2.8, 5.8, 5.3, 4.6, 6.3, 4.8, 7.8, 
3.6, 5.8, 9.1, 2.9, 3.6, 3.5, 3.2, 2, 5.9, 6.8, 3.3, 8.9, NA, 
7.1, NA, 3.4, 7.6, 4.9, 4.6, 2.4, 2.8, 1.9, 1.9, 4, NA, 2.9, 
2.7, 7.5, 2.6, 4.8, 1.9, 5.4, 3.2, 3.6, 7.2, 2.5, 1.6, 7.8, 6.1, 
4.3, 3.8, 4.5, 7.4, NA, 2.6, 2.7, 2.4, 2, NA, 5.5, 4.3, 2.6, 
2.8, 3.8, 1.5, 7.1, NA, 3.7, 4.9, 5.7, 8, 5.3, 3.3, NA, NA, 3.7, 
NA, 3.5, 2.8, NA, 3.4, 4.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1, 3.8, 3, 3, 5.2, 3.7, 
5, 3.4, 2.5, 2.8, 8.3, 8.6, 3.1, NA, 9.1, 4.7, 2.8, 3.5, NA, 
3.8, 3.6, 2.5, 6, 6.2, 0.8, 6.2, 2.4, 6.8, 4.3, 2.8, 5.3, NA, 
4.6, 4.1, 8.6, NA, 3, 3.8, NA, 0.8, 4.2, 1.1, 4.7, 5.7, 8.9, 
3.9, 5.4, 1.7, 1.9, 2.9, 3.5, 2.2, 1.7, 3, NA, 3.8, 4.1, 5, NA, 
6.1, 3.3, 2.6, 2.5, 7.3, 7.3, 1.7, 6.2, 2, 3.1, NA, NA, 1.8, 
4.2, 4.2, 2.2, 3.8, 2.1), GCB2013 = c(NA, NA, 46, NA, NA, NA, 
13, 18, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 39, 8, NA, NA, 28, NA, 
NA, 36, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 7, 10, NA, NA, 62, NA, 22, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 19, 15, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 41, NA, 36, NA, 2, 
6, 44, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 54, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 12, 36, 54, NA, NA, 29, NA, 12, 5, 12, 37, 
1, NA, 34, 70, 45, 57, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 75, 62, NA, NA, 19, 
NA, 26, NA, 19, 16, NA, NA, 49, NA, 29, 28, 3, 33, 17, NA, NA, 
NA, 45, 62, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 44, NA, NA, 3, 31, NA, 3, NA, 
34, NA, NA, 20, 12, 27, NA, NA, NA, 3, 25, NA, 17, NA, 13, NA, 
NA, 57, NA, 34, 84, 12, NA, NA, NA, 17, 21, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18, 21, NA, 36, 56, 61, 37, 3, 
7, NA, NA, 27, 30, 13, NA, 74, 26, 47, 46, NA, 62)), .Names = c("country", 
"wbcode", "CPI2013", "GCB2013"), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To expand on Akrun's answer: `text` is a function for adding points to plots generated through R's base plotting system (e.g. `plot`). `ggplot` is a different plotting system, so `text` returns an error because it can't find an open `plot` window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `geom_text` from `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(TreismanData3, aes(CPI2013, GCB2013)) + 
        geom_point(position = "jitter", na.rm = TRUE) + 
        geom_smooth(method = loess) + 
        labs(x="Perception", y="Experience")+
        theme_bw() + 
        geom_text(aes(label = wbcode))
```